# Quick clarification question concerning the notion of "base point" in metric topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The following are taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

$\textit{The categories}$ $\textbf{Met1}$ $\textit{and}$ $\textbf{Met*.}$  Let $\textbf{Met1}$ be the category whose objects are metric spaces $(X,d)$ $\textit{of diameter}$ $\leq 1$ (that is, $d(x,y)\leq 1$ for all $x,y$) and whose morphisms are contractions. Let $\textbf{Met*}$ be the category whose objects are $\textit{metric spaces with base point}$ $(X,d,x)$ (meaning $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $x$ is "the base point" is an arbitrary element of $X$)

Example: (Exercise:) Consider $\mathbb{\textbf{R}_{+}}$ to be in $\textbf{Met*.}$ with the usual metric and $0$ as a base point......

$\textbf{Question:}$

I would like some clarification on the notion of "base point". Is "base point" about an arbitrary fixed point $x_0$ or is it referring to an arbitrary point $x$?  I see in the included example exercise above referring to $0$ as a base point, but in other context from other topology books, I see it referred to an arbitrary fixed point, or sometimes an arbitrary point.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A base point is a distinguished point in the space, so the pointed space $X=(\mathbb{R},d,0)$ is a different pointed space to $Y=(\mathbb{R},d,1)$.

Base points can be useful for a variety of reasons (for example when defining the fundamental group of a space). Often, when working with pointed spaces, one restricts the allowed morphisms just to those that map base points to base points, so for example, the identity would not be an allowed morphism $X \to Y$ for $X$ and $Y$ defined above, but the function $x \mapsto x+1$ would be.

Comment: so base point refers to a specific point that one chooses?

Comment: Yes, it's a specific point that is a core piece of information that is a part of the definition of your object.

Comment: ah kk, thank you for clarifying it up for me.  :)